# Spring boot application query - H2 Db NameGenerator.generateColumnNames - null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a spring boot application with spring data which is connected to an oracle database. When the application load with the oracle connections it starts successfully. However for my integration test when I use H2 db the following query fails:

```
@Query("SELECT new dummy.domain.dto.RevenueCollDTO(sum(d.amount), " +
        "TO_CHAR(d.Id.date, 'MM'), d.Id.years)  FROM RevenueCollection d WHERE d.Id.date " +
        "BETWEEN TO_DATE(:startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(:endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')" +
        " GROUP BY TO_CHAR(d.Id.date, 'MM'), d.Id.years ORDER BY d.Id.years ASC, TO_CHAR(d.Id.date, 'MM') ASC ")
List<RevenueCollDTO> getAllRevenueCollectionByDate(String startDate, String endDate);
```

The error log is shown below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.NameGenerator.generateColumnNames(NameGenerator.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.generateColumnNames(SessionFactoryHelper.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeColumnNames(SelectClause.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.finishInitialization(SelectClause.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:1026)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
    ... 114 common frames omitted
```

Please find my entity below:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "REVENUE_COLL")
@Getter
@Setter
public class RevenueCollection {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Revenue Id;

    @Column(name = "AMUNT")
    private Long amount;

    @Column(name = "BDGETDES")
    private String budgetDesc;

    @Column(name = "TXDESC")
    private String taxDesc;

}


@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class Revenue implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "CODATE")
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "COYEAR")
    private int years;

    @Column(name = "TAXCDE")
    private String taxCode;
    
    @Column(name = "BDGTCDE")
    private String budgetCode;

}
```

My integration test is define as below:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest()
public class ServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    @Sql("classpath:/sql/createUserFunction.sql")
     public void testUserInfo() throws Exception {
        
        userService.isUserValid("test","test");
      
    }

}
```

Any idea why it is failing with H2 db please?